# How to implement dynamic select2 field in my flask web app?

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms

**HTML**

```
<select id='selUser' style='width: 200px;'>
  <option value='0'>- Search user -</option>
</select><br><br>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#selUser").select2({
            ajax: { 
                url: "{{ url_for('main.add_user') }}",
                type: "POST",
                dataType: 'json',
                delay: 250,
                data: function (params) {
                    return {
                        searchTerm: params.term // search term
                    };
                },
                processResults: function (response) {
                    return {
                        results: response
                    };
                },
                cache: true
           }
       });
   });
</script>
```

**Python route :**

```
@main.route('/add_user', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def add_user():     
    form = AddUserForm()
    a = Group.query.with_entities(Group.name)
    groups = []
    for b in a:
        groups.append(b[0])
    data = {
        'groupNames': groups
    }
    groups = json.dumps(groups)

    if form.validate_on_submit():
        User.create_user(
            user=form.name.data,
            email=form.email.data,
            password=form.password.data,
            groups=form.group.data)
        flash(' User Registration Successful')
    return render_template('add_user.html', form=form,data=data)
```

What to do in my route ? Group is my model..From the route i have the list of group names i need to send to the select 2 box but i did not know how to implement..please clarify!!
How to send the group names to ajax and display it in select2 box

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SelectField` from `wtform`.

In the example below, I define the class `AddUserForm` which inherits from `FlaskForm`, with a field (`groups`) of type selectfield.

Then in the `add_user` route, I populate the **group field** with the names of the groups obtained following the database query.

```
# your other imports here
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import SelectField

class AddUserForm(FlaskForm):
    # your other fields here
    groups = SelectField('Groups')


@main.route('/add_user', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def add_user():     
    form = AddUserForm()
    a = Group.query.with_entities(Group.name)
    form.groups.choice = [(i[0], i[0]) for i in a]

    if form.validate_on_submit():
        User.create_user(
            user=form.name.data,
            email=form.email.data,
            password=form.password.data,
            groups=form.groups.data)
        flash(' User Registration Successful')
    return render_template('add_user.html', form=form, data=data)
```